# Has anyone integrated Test Rail with Cypress ? I am looking to auto update the status of test case

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to integrate test rail with cypress to auto update the Test Case status. I followed the steps as mentioned: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-testrail-reporter

But I see the following error in cypress run:

> EPROTO 140623370270312:error:100000f0:SSL
> routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL:../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake_client.cc:581:

Is this because the Test Rail set up done in domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the following configurations in cypress.json

```
"reporter": "cypress-testrail-reporter",
"reporterOptions": {
"domain": "yourdomain.testrail.com",  without https e.g (test.testrail.com)
"username": "username",            , Add user name 
"password": "password",            , Add password-Api key is recommend
"projectId": 1,
"suiteId": 1,
```

}

Do let me know if you face any issues..

2nd option we can go with testrail Api directly and we can do the same thing without npm package will explain if the above solution is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Does this update the test rail test id with results as pass or fail ?  I tried the Solution1 but it doesn't updating the testcase. I added runId as well as it was throwing an error. "reporter":"autoset-status-cypress-testrail-reporter",
"reporterOptions":{
"host":"URL",
"username":"username",
"password":"password",
"projectId":38, //This is ProjectId on Dashboard  
"suiteId":148, //This is suiteId I captured from "index.php?/suites/view/148&"  
"runId":543 //This is test Run Id it’s a string R543 
}
Added case number in script as "it("C372 Login to Console"

Comment: @Arushi yes its working fine for me and we some other packages as well. can you please share exact error ?

Comment: Thanks Mehran for helping out with this.

Comment: Welcome @Arushi